# Increasing Heap Size upto 6GB

Tags: java, heap-memory

I was looking at the following article:
[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Now I have a program that needs about 5GB memory and while doing what was told in the article (that is increasing heap size by using -Xmx5g in the arguments field), I am still getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

My system is Windows 7 (64 bit) with 8GB RAM. Am I doing something wrong? If yes, how shall I proceed to get 5GB of heap memory or it is just not feasible for my system to handle?

Note: I have to do calculations with a 2D matrix that is of 25K*25K size having all non-zero values. Hence I cannot use sparse matrix as well.

Comment: can you please list the parameter as you have configured them ?

Comment: Set 6G of memory and see result. I think, 5G is not enough to your program or you have not 5G free system memory.

Comment: @salah-I just added -Xmx5g in the arguments field if that what you were asking.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev: tried that as well.. still got the same exception.

Comment: 1. Do you use java 64bit? 2. Check memory usage with some appropriate tool (eg. *jvisualvm*)

Comment: What is the element type in the matrix? Reducing `double` to `float` (if your able to give up precision) will halve the memory consumption.

Comment: Were you running the program in cmd or eclipse?

Comment: @Bathsheba: i think that should work.. lemme try :)

Comment: As an alternative, you can persist semi-calculated value on disc temporarily. Read-write at certain row and column

Comment: @locoyou: i am using eclipse juno

Comment: @Beginner Then you should put the -Xmx5G in the VM arguments instead of program arguments :)

Comment: @locoyou: oh man !! so that was the problem.. lets see.. I think I might get away with your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

`OutOfMemoryError` is thrown when JVM does not have enough memory for objects being allocated. If you defined heap of `5G` this almost definitely mean that you have a kind of memory leak. For example I can write very simple code that will cause `OutOfMemoryError` at any environment:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
while(true) {
    list.add("a");
}
```

Run this code and wait several seconds. `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown. This is because I add strings to list and never clean it.

I believe that something similar happens with your application.

I understand, that it is not so trivial as my example, so you will probably have to  use profiler to debug it and understand the reason of your memory leak.

EDIT:
I've just saw that you are working with 25K*25K martrix. It means that you have 625M cells. You have not mentioned the type of the matrix but if it is `int` that occupies 4 bytes you need 625*4=2500M=2.5G memory, so 5G should be enough.

Please try to analyze what else happens in your program and where your memory is spent.

Answer (score 1):

5G/(25K*25K) ~ 8 bytes.

Generously assuming that you program does not use memory except for that matrix, each matrix element must take no more than 8 bytes.

You should calculate at least approximate memory requirements to check whether it is even possible to handle problem of such size on your hardware. For example, if you need a 2D array of MxN size of `double` values then you need *at least* 8*M*N bytes of memory.

Comment: Well (8*M*N)b + 128m I'd say, you need breathing space for the application outside of that matrix too ;)